# EventSource connect to localhost SSE server

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, server-sent-events

I have a local SSE server that is sending messages on port 8080. I would like to read them from the browser using `EventSource` as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource/EventSource).

But if I type the following in the browser console:

```
var evtSource = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:8080', {});
```

I get an error:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/.
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (“connect-src”).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your pages csp has denied it